# Unable to create mysql trigger from php

Tags: php, mysql

How do I use php and mysql to create the following trigger for each table created.

I want to convert the following code to be used as a sql query from php.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER trigger1
BEFORE INSERT
ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @cnt FROM table1;
  IF @cnt >= 25 THEN
    CALL sth();
  END IF;
END
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

I tried to use the following but it does not work.

```
if ($method == "T")// method is activated if $_GET["method'] = T  method is set to T in script to allways return true
{
$sql = "CREATE TRIGGER TRIGGER1
BEFORE INSERT
ON 49a64d6512
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @cnt FROM 49a64d6512;
IF @cnt >=25 THEN
CALL sth();
END IF;
END";
echo '1';
}
```

Is what i am trying to do even possible?

Comment: so does this pan out at all `if ($method == "T")`? and are you querying that? a few unknowns here.

Comment: Sorry ignore if ($method =="T") that just chooses witch sql statement to use. I just need to figure out how to make the query.

Comment: I'd guess it's possible as long as your user has a permission. Your user has a permission to create `trigger`? But why would you want to do so in PHP? Is there any reason why you don't run `CREATE TRIGGER` directly on your MySQL server? I'd think creating trigger has to be done one time only.

Comment: because the tables are created dynamicly by th game engine thru php so i need trigger created hen a new table is.